# Remove letter upper form keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

Is it possible to remove  letter upper from keyboard ?

[image]

Comment: You could pry it loose with a screwdriver.

Comment: no it is not possible in native keyboard , if you are use the custom keyboard extension u can change/ modify anything

Answer (score 1):

Not if its the standard `UIKeyboard`. You can roll your own keyboard that does not support uppercase. Alternatively, for an easier solution you can make all text lowercase when entered via a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Custom Keyboard with iOS8 App Extension. Try this tutorial :

http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/

Also check at developer.apple.com :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

> A custom keyboard replaces the system keyboard for users who want
>   capabilities such as a novel text input method or the ability to enter
>   text in a language not otherwise supported in iOS. The essential
>   function of a custom keyboard is simple: Respond to taps, gestures, or
>   other input events and provide text, in the form of an unattributed
>   NSString object, at the text insertion point of the current text input
>   object.